# Passing url as argument in java

Tags: java, url

I give url as parameter to my java code, i have a script which i use to call my java code:

```
java -cp lib/aspose-cells-8.0.1.jar:lib/json-20140107.jar:lib/jsoup-1.7.3.jar:bin jsoup.$@
```

when i run my script with url, my url is seperated to parts beacuse of "&" symbol

```
bash myscript.sh MyJavaCode http://www.mavi.com/Erkek/Gomlek/c/3-4?pageSize=all&q=%3AtopRated&sort=topRated#
```

i want my java code accept this url as one parameter, but unfortunately my code take this url as 3 part:

1. http://www.mavi.com/Erkek/Gomlek/c/3-4?pageSize=all
2. q=%3AtopRated
3. sort=topRated#

Comment: Did you try to surround your url with double quotes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting it in "" so it parses as a string arg.

Comment: "" helps me, but sometimes i need to pass two argument, first parameter is url, second parameter is pagination number,

Comment: add a comma  and an int. If you're running a main method than java passes in all your arguments in a String[] args array.

Comment: don't need to add comma. main(String []args) can split by ' '(space). When you retrieve just take by the index. like 'number = args[1];'